# jsp:useBean, using previously created session scoped bean

Tags: java, jsp, servlets, javabeans

I'm trying to use "jsp:useBean" to load a previously created bean.

In one page (one .jsp file) I use

```
<jsp:useBean id="cart" class="beans.shoppingCartBean" scope="session" />
```

to create a session scoped bean. On another page (another .jsp file) which is linked to from the first page I want to load the "cart" bean and get som property for it. This work fine if I use a scriptlet to directly access the "cart" attribute in the session object. But I when I try to do it using a jsp tag I can't get it to work. Shouldn't I be able to do this?

I've tried:

```
<jsp:useBean id="cart" scope="session" />
<jsp:getProperty name="cart" property="xml" />
```

and only using the first or second line, and varying which attributes I specify for the tags but I keep getting a server error page in the browser if either or both of these lines are included in the code.

The server error is:

"Server error.

The website encountered an error while retrieving 'localhost:8080/PizzaStore/Shopy'. It may be down for maintenance or configured incorrectly"

So how should I do this? Can I do this? And should I do this?

Comment: The error contains the answer. Please don't ignore it, but interpret it. If you're unable to, just share it here so that we can translate it for you in layman's terms.

Comment: Is there a reason you need to use a passe tag like jsp:useBean?  You could get the job done with less code by doing ${sessionScope.cart.xml} to access the xml property.

Answer (score 0):

The `class` attribute is always needed whether you're creating or retrieving the bean.

```
<jsp:useBean id="cart" class="beans.shoppingCartBean" scope="session" />
<p>My session cart speaks xml: <jsp:getProperty name="cart" property="xml" /></p>
```